# boolean table sql best approach

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I want to store the current situation of a patient

- Entry
- In Body Treatment
- High Medical

What would be the best approach to store a boolean table like this?

I was thinking

```
ID_STATUS   INT
ID_PATIENT  INT 
ENTRY       BOOL
BODY_TREATMENT  BOOL
HIGH_MEDICAL    BOOL
```

Is this a good approach or only a table like the following is needed ?

```
ID_STATUS         INT
ID_PATIENT        INT
CURRENT_STATUS    VARCHAR
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of your domain it's **impossible to tell**. AFAIK, these tables are not compatible at all: they do completely different things. You must know something you haven't told us. (E.g. What does `CURRENT_STATUS` do?)

Comment: You've been around for a while and with your current reputation i'm surprised you even ask a question like this. You know how it works by now and that there is so much information missing.

Comment: Are these statuses _exclusive_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your `CURRENT_STATUS` possibilities in a lookup table.  You can use a surrogate key or not. This is personal preference but should probably follow what the rest of the database looks like.

Boolean columns are somewhat of a code smell. "Flags" like this can often be refactored into better relational structures. In your case, would it make sense if two statuses were true at the same time?

Comment: ANSI SQL ***does*** define a boolean datatype. And I do not aggree that they are "code smell". What about a flag `active`? That is a perfectly valid use-case for a boolean column. But I do agree that the status is better put into a lookup table with a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Yes, I yanked this part before I even saw your good comment. I see boolean was added in SQL:1999 as an optional (and nullable) type. However, I agree with Celko on booleans and I can't tell you how many times I've asked another developer, "what does this null flag mean?" and gotten a blank stare. Or seen them abused in the manner the OP first suggests. Active flags for soft-deletes can often be better implemented as a datetime if they are _truly_ necessary (and don't have other possible statuses), though I don't see them as a great method for archiving.

Comment: I see `bit` [was deprecated](http://books.google.com/books?id=W2Yi4TQaAjwC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=celko+boolean&source=bl&ots=sH6MtlQLJg&sig=7PV-BL2IL7FHrOJDggMrykAbkfg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A-eHUcnILcWs4AOf7oCQDQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=celko%20boolean&f=false) in SQL:2003.

Comment: I use boolean only together with a NOT NULL constraint ;)

Comment: Ha, no joke! I assumed as much given your rep and excellent answers that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about when one situation stops and the next one starts, all you need is:

```
id_patient
id_situation
```

That's an oversimplification of course, because a patient can have more than one visit and each visit would have it's own situation.